# encrypted internet sharing don't work for android phones

Tags: wi-fi

i have a snow leopard macbook and a Android cell phone. when i try share internet to my android cell phone from my mac in unsecure mode it works but when i try encrypted wifi then my android always give authentication errors and something like that. can i connect the phone to internet with cable ?